# Proof of Pascal's theorem for a degenerate conic

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-explanation

In our algebraic geometry course we went through the proof of Pascal's theorem for irreducible conics. We were asked to supply the proof of Pascal's theorem in the degenerate case ourselves. I can't figure out why it's true in the latter case.

Since $F \in \mathbb{R}[X,Y]$ is reducible, we may write $F = GH$, where $G,H \in \mathbb{R}[X,Y]$, and both are of the form $a_1X+a_2Y + a_3$, for $a_i \in \mathbb{R}$. Consider $G$ first, $\{G=0\} = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: a_1x+a_2y+a_3 = 0\}$. But this is equal to the set $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: y = -\frac{a_1}{a_2}x - \frac{a_3}{a_2}\}$, i.e., a line.

But if both $H$ and $G$ produce lines, we may have the lines $\{H=0\}$ and $\{G=0\}$ being parallel. But if this is the case, then we may choose 3 points on each of $\{H=0\}$ and $\{G=0\}$, such that every point of $\{H=0\}$ is connected to another point on $\{G=0\}$, where this connecting line is perpendicular to both $\{H=0\}$ and $\{G=0\}$. But then, these connecting lines are again all parallel, so their intersection is the empty set.

In this case there is no 'line' that the points lie on because there are no points correct? So how can Pascal's theorem be true in general for the degenerate case? Am I misunderstanding the theorem?